# split string into multiple rows with multiple columns

Tags: oracle, insert, string, regex

I have a string with user information. I have to write a function that takes string as input and inserts into some table.

Input string contains multiple rows with multiple columns like following:

```
inputString= "1,cassey,1222,12-12-12:2,timon,,02-02-12:3,john,3333,03-03-12"
```

what i want is to create insert from this...

How it can be achieved?

Comment: does the input string always contain the same sequence of column/value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split/explode comma delimited string field into SQL query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51421/split-explode-comma-delimited-string-field-into-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Solution in a single Query as following:
But I replaced the ',,' with 'NULL'

```
inputString= "1,cassey,1222,12-12-12:2,timon,NULL,02-02-12:3,john,3333,03-03-12"

                SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputString, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL), '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS Col1,
                       REGEXP_SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputString, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL), '[^,]+', 1, 2) AS Col2,
                       REGEXP_SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputString, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL), '[^,]+', 1, 3) AS Col3,
                       REGEXP_SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputString, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL), '[^,]+', 1, 4) AS Col4
                  FROM DUAL 
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE (inputString, '[^:]+')) + 1;
```

Result:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
------  ------  ------  ------
1       cassey  1222    12-12-12
2       timon   NULL    02-02-12
3       john    3333    03-03-12


3 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Package Spec:

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE string_conversion AS

TYPE string_test_tab IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000);

TAB string_test_tab;

PROCEDURE string_convert(v_input IN VARCHAR2, v_output OUT string_test_tab);

END string_conversion;

/

Package Body:

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY string_conversion AS

PROCEDURE string_convert(v_input IN VARCHAR2, v_output OUT string_test_tab) IS

```
v_index NUMBER := 1;

v_index_comma NUMBER := 1;

TAB2 string_test_tab;

v_input_str VARCHAR2(2000):= v_input||',';
```

BEGIN

```
v_output := string_test_tab();

LOOP

  v_index_comma := INSTR (v_input_str, ',',v_index);

  EXIT WHEN v_index_comma = 0;

  v_output.extend();

  v_output(v_output.count):= SUBSTR(v_input_str, v_index, v_index_comma - v_index);

  dbms_output.put_line(v_output(v_output.count));

  v_index := v_index_comma + 1; 

END LOOP;
```

END string_convert;

END string_conversion;

/

Testing:

DECLARE

v_out1 string_conversion.string_test_tab;

BEGIN

string_conversion.string_convert('a,b,c,d,e',v_out1);

FOR j IN v_out1.FIRST .. v_out1.LAST

LOOP

```
  dbms_output.put_line(v_out1(j));
```

END LOOP;

END;
/

OUTPUT:

a

b

c

d

e

Comment: Could you also add some explanation?

Comment: string_test_tab is a PLSQL Table, create table "TAB" of type string_test_tab.If Input(v_input) is "a,b,c,d,e" then the value of v_input_str will be "a,b,c,d,e," Storing and returning the output through the variable v_output which is of type string_test_tab. v_index_comma is used to get the index(position) of comma. extend() is used to append(add) rows in the PLSQL table through v_ouput. (v_ouput.count) will get the count of rows in the PLSQL Table. SUBSTR fun. will get the alphabets from v_input and it will be added in PLSQL table and the loop continues till value of v_index_comma becomes zero

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE

v_string VARCHAR2(20) := 'a,b,c,d,e';

v_val VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN

  dbms_output.put_line('v_string = '||v_string);

LOOP

    v_val := SUBSTR(v_string,1, INSTR(v_string, ',', 1)-1);

    IF INSTR(v_string, ',', 1) = 0 THEN

      v_val := v_string;

    END IF;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_val);

    EXIT WHEN INSTR(v_string, ',', 1) = 0;

    v_string := SUBSTR(v_string,INSTR(v_string, ',', 1)+1);

END LOOP;

END;
```